Fourier transform for function restricted to a line
Given $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, we can define the fourier transform of $f$, $\hat{f}$ by $\hat{f}(\xi) := \int _{\mathbb{R}^{n}}f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\cdot \xi} \, dx$.

Now consider the function $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and $x_{0},h\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $\|h\|=1$, and define $g(t) = f(x_0+th)$. How does the fourier transform of $g$ $i$.$e$. $\hat{g}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}  f(x_{0}+th)e^{-2\pi it\xi} \, dt$ relate to $\hat{f}$

I think maybe it's particularly interesting if for instance f is radial, and $x_0$ is $0$.
The basic Fourier identities doesn't seem to work as in this case we are dealing with a fourier transform of a function in $\mathbb{R}$. So I'm a little clueless of what can be done. I thought about this while learning harmonic analysis, mostly out of curiosity.

Be careful that $\widehat{g}$, the Fourier transform of $g$ you are considering, is defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

Let me re-denote $x_{0}$ by $v$.
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n} h_{k}\int _{\mathbb{R}}f(v+t h)e^{-2\pi i (v_{k}+t h_{k})\cdot \xi_{k}}  dt=\int _{x=v+t h}f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\cdot \xi}  dx.$$

You can simplify the product on the left side and write it in terms of $\widehat{g}$ as you wish.
